# How does Python threadsafe queue work after calling get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

In the example from documentation:

```
import threading, queue

q = queue.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        print(f'Working on {item}')
        print(f'Finished {item}')
        q.task_done()

# turn-on the worker thread
threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

# send thirty task requests to the worker
for item in range(30):
    q.put(item)
print('All task requests sent\n', end='')

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()
print('All work completed')
```

After the worker thread get from the queue, which i assume is protected by some lock and checking the queue and modifying the queue is atomic, it does prints. How are the prints also atomic across all the worker threads and we won't see intermingled prints?

Comment: You have only one worker thread.

Comment: right, sorry for the confusion, I am asking about when there are multiple worker threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your threads print to stdout, which is a shared global object. One possible solution is to use a threading.Lock or threading.Semaphore to guard stdout. For example:

```
import threading, queue
  
print_semaphore = threading.Semaphore()

q = queue.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        with print_semaphore:
            print(f'Working on {item}')
            print(f'Finished {item}')
        q.task_done()

# turn-on the worker thread
threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

# send thirty task requests to the worker
for item in range(99):
    q.put(item)
    with print_semaphore:
        print('All task requests sent\n', end='')

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()
with print_semaphore:
    print('All work completed')
```

Another solution would be to introduce another queue, and have your threads put messages to that queue, instead of printing to stdout directly.